# Move cup like 3d after Wrap whole image on cylindrical cup in javascript three.js html5

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I want to rotate cup like 3d after wrap image on cylindrical cup.
[image]

i want to rotate mug like 3d

Comment: Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].